# Selecting data from Excel CSV using iMacro

Tags: csv, imacros

I want to select values from two excel sheet(CSV) using imacro

Example:

Sheet 1 is having 2 values 
Sheet 2 is having 3 values 
I want to select the values from both the sheets so that i can fill form using imacro

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
SET !DATASOURCE Chrometest.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 8
URL GOTO=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCr5ZoLQFLw8ZUnRSOdwP-wuyPXpZbd-uWe7-DkHkBt47QVw/viewform
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_757433527 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_414022470 CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_1960753282 CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_549681952 CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_436972228 CONTENT={{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_1842450612 CONTENT={{!COL6}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_926019437 CONTENT={{!COL7}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_1850440789 CONTENT={{!COL8}}
```

please help

Comment: At first you should view [this wiki page](http://wiki.imacros.net/!DATASOURCE).

Comment: sorry i didn't get u bro , do u know or not

Comment: Hey, do you want me to write the whole macro for you?.. Besides the wiki there are a lot of examples of how to read data from csv-files here on the 'stackoverflow' forum. Post some code that you tried and probably you'll get an answer.

Comment: i have placed my code now tell me where can i mention in the code to take the values from different sheets

Comment: ... `SET !DATASOURCE Chrometest_your_first_sheet.csv` ... `SET !DATASOURCE Chrometest_your_second_sheet.csv` ...

Comment: Hi Bro thanks but i want i macro to read sheet within the excel csv files  bro not to read from two different files please tell me

Comment: 'iMacros' can't read Excel files ('xls', 'xlsx' etc.). You have to use only 'csv' (text) files.

Comment: it Reads when an excel is saved in a CSV format bro .i have used excel only for this code

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a very simple format and doesn't have the concept of a Sheets. The only ways is, you pass to multiple csv files.
Following code will work:

```
SET !DATASOURCE Chrometestfile1.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
URL GOTO=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCr5ZoLQFLw8ZUnRSOdwP-wuyPXpZbd-uWe7-DkHkBt47QVw/viewform
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_757433527 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_414022470 CONTENT={{!COL2}}
SET !DATASOURCE Chrometestfile2.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_1960753282 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_549681952 CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ss-form ATTR=ID:entry_436972228 CONTENT={{!COL3}}
```